# Windows serial: discard all bytes received in the input buffer before a start bytes received

Tags: c++, string, windows, serial-port, arduino-uno

I'm doing a project where I should parse incoming sensors data in my C++ application. The sensors data are sent by Arduino via serial communication to Windows. The data contain string like this:

> $12.345,12.345,12.345,12.345* (+ newline and carriage return)

The sensors data could be 35-46 bytes. The serial port between these two is established using CreateFile Windows function and configured as synchronous and like this:

> Baud rate: 38400
>
> Byte size: 8
>
> Parity: None
>
> Stop bits: 1

I tried to see the incoming data on the Arduino IDE as well as on hterm. The data come properly as they should be. However, my application receives the data "unregular". Like sometimes, the ReadFile function read from the middle of the string + the concatenated next string:

> 12.345*\n\r$67.890,67.890,67.890,67.890*

Therefore, I would ask if it is possible to set the Windows serial to discard any characters which come into input buffer before the '$' symbol arrived?

Answer (score 0):

Serial port communication is basically character-based communication, not packet-based delimited communication such as TCP/IP.

It is not always possible for the receiving side to read the data written once by the sending side, and it is possible that multiple written data can be received together with one read.

You must understand this, treat all received data as valid data, analyze it, and cut it out for each delimiter unit.

Data that has not reached the delimiter unit must be concatenated with data that will be received later, and data of sufficient length must be received before analysis.

Correct communication will not be possible if fragmented data is discarded.

Please discard only what appears to be noise or invalid data in the analysis results.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It's clear now that it is a "normal" occurence, so that I need to treat the incoming data accordingly.